# Reopen request on question about fried foods

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[What is the best way to keep the quality of fried food?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/96643/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-the-quality-of-fried-food) was recently closed as a duplicate of [Best way to hold deep-fried foods?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20297/best-way-to-hold-deep-fried-foods). However the former is asking about storage methods of still hot food for delivery and the latter is asking for cooling, refrigerating and reheating instructions.

Comment: Thank you for posting this! This is exactly how the community is supposed to work, by discussing closures here on Meta, and for some time we moderators have been worried that people are not doing it. I am excited to see this finally happening. On a side note, I suggested an alternative approach in an answer. If you prefer your own suggestion, it would be easiest if you post an answer of your own and we can see which way the votes go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very good catch, thanks! I didn't notice the difference when closing the question.

If that was all we have in duplicates, I would be OK with reopening. However, we also have at least three questions on transporting food while keeping it crispy: [How to keep fried fish warm and crispy during transport to venue?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/38202/how-to-keep-fried-fish-warm-and-crispy-during-transport-to-venue), [Crispy fried chicken goes limp: picnic disaster](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/crispy-fried-chicken-goes-limp-picnic-disaster) and [How to keep my pizza hot and crispy during transport](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/94360/how-to-keep-my-pizza-hot-and-crispy-during-transport?noredirect=1). I actually think we must have more, they just didn't turn up using the search query [transport crispy].

It is true that the OP in the closed question asked for French fries, but none of the answers in these questions are specific to the food being transported, and I don't see much value to the site in keeping the answers strewn under different questions just because the name of the food is different. Since closed duplicates are not deleted, the next person seeking how to keep French fries crispy will find the information easily if the question is closed as a duplicate of one of those.

So my suggestion here is to reopen and close it again as a duplicate of the fish question, which seems to have some nice sugegstions in the answers. I won't act on it though until this Meta question has had time to gather some alternative answers and votes.

Comment: @bruglesco And of course, if we do this, it will be appropriate to repost your answer under the duplicate target.

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/90355/best-way-to-store-and-rewarm-fried-chicken/90358#90358 also closely related, but not a dupe. I also upvoted. The answers to the fish question more closely answer the needs of the OP of the FF Question.

Comment: Is it worth changing still?

Comment: \*ping\* It's been nearly two weeks, so it's probably time to close as a dupe of the question you feel is most appropriate.